# Can't get pagination to work in a div

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page showing a picture of a product. Underneath that I have tabs for the `Description`, `Contact Details` and `Comments`. When you click on the `Comments` tab a comments page is loaded into the `div="info"` using `Jquery`.

products.php:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="image.jpg">
<hr> 
<a id="det"><h3>Details</h3></a> &nbsp<a id="contact"><h3>Contact</h3></a>
 &nbsp<a id="comments"><h3>Comments</h3></a>

<div id="info"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#comments").click(function(){
      $("#info").load("comments.php");
   });
});
</script>
```

The comments.php page below uses pagination for the comments.

When I click on the pagination links the page refreshes the `comments.php?page=*` removing it from the `div="info"`.How do I keep the comments in the div `id="info"` when I use `pagination`?

comments.php:

```
<?php
// 1)Set current page
$current_page = ((isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) ?    
(int)$_GET['page'] : 1);

require 'connect.php';
// 2)Get total amount of rows
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// Offset - calculation to skip to the data you want to display
 $results_per_page = 10;
 $offset = ($current_page-1)*$results_per_page;
 ?>

 /*------- Comments Form -----*/
 /*------- Comments from Database ---- */

 <?php

   //Here is the code for displaying link and page number.
   $number_page = $totalrows/$results_per_page;
   for ( $page = 1; $page <= $number_page; $page ++ )
   {
     echo "<a href='comments.php?page={$page}'>{$page}</a>";
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: You need to look at ajax. Just Google jQuery ajax tutorial.

Comment: Oh now i see... the current page redirects when you click on the pagination?

Comment: Yes,that was the problem I was having.Thanks for the help Clyff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know... you could end this problem doing a `js` making every link inside the `#info` element update only inside it. Not sure if is that what you need.

```
$('#info').on('click', 'a', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#info").load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to load a file/url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a click event to the links that are loaded in the ajax partial.
The simplest way to do that is to add a **class** property to any of the links you want to load via ajax, then attach your event to that class.

Example:

```
<?php
// example just increments the page param
if(strtolower(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die('<a class="ajaxlink" href="?page='.($_GET['page']+1).'">Goto page '.($_GET['page']+1).'</a>');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h3><a class="ajaxlink" href="index.php">Contact</a></h3>

        <div id="info"></div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".ajaxlink", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ($(this).prop('href').length > 0) {
                $("#info").load($(this).prop('href'));
            }
            return false;
        });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful,I was just looking for the Jquery code,but I wasn't sure that  that was all I needed.